# Cannot modify scope properties using this

Tags: angularjs, model-view-controller, angularjs-scope

I have a controller dynamically loaded:

```
(function() {
  "use strict";

  APP.loadController("dynamicDemoController", dynamicDemoController);
  dynamicDemoController.$inject = ["NgTableParams", "$scope"];

  function dynamicDemoController(NgTableParams, $scope) {
    var self = this;

    self.A = 'hello';

    self.edit = function(){
      self.A = 'edit';
    };

    self.printIt = function(){
     alert(self.A); // <-- print the old value 'hello', why?
    };
  }

})();
```

And 1 view lazy loading a modal box calling twice `ng-controller="dynamicDemoController as demo"`.

Clicking a button on the view containing: `ng-click="demo.edit()"` doesn't change the A value. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I think the key statement here is "calling twice..." however, without seeing your code it isn't a guarantee.  it ***sounds like*** you are trying to re-use a controller, once on the page and then again in a modal.  Unfortunately, Controllers aren't singletons, and each time you create one, you are getting a new instance, so the modal controller can't change the page controller's data.

Comment: I saw that variables are somehow "shared" but changes are not: https://plnkr.co/edit/5J4VH9WjYYH4pzgI2BmS?p=preview

Comment: variables aren't "shared", the *entire* controller code is run every time the controller is instantiated, so you are declaring the same variables multiple times.  each `this` refers to a specific instance of `dynamicDemoController`, and each instance has an `A` that is **initially** set to `'hello'`.

Comment: in fact, your code doesn't really need to be written the way it is;  the way you wrote it, you have 3 instances of the controller, for no reason at all.  You have a parent controller on the `body` element, and two more instances of the controller each on their own `div` inside the parent.  if these extra controllers on the `div` elements were removed, then both `button` elements would have access to the ***same*** instance of the controller, and everything would work as expected.

Comment: @Claies This is just a basic sample. My code actually involves more complex async loading and tons of service.. btw thanks.

Comment: right, I do understand.  my point is, if you need to share data between two controllers, **even when the controllers are named the same**, you should put the data in a service object.  and a secondary point I can make is that it's not recommended to re-use a controller for more than one page section, due to this kind of confusion.

Answer (score 0):

```
  <div ng-controller="dynamicDemoController as demo">
    {{demo.A}}
    <button ng-click="demo.edit()">edit</button>
  </div>

  <div ng-controller="dynamicDemoController as demo">
    {{demo.A}}
    <button ng-click="demo.printIt()">print</button>
  </div>
```

In this case controller gets re initialized, i.e it gets instantiated again, since you are setting the A variable to hello , it will print it as hell. Actually it does not share the variable. In order to fix that, have a common controller for both buttons so the variable will be common and gets changed whenever you want to within the controller and scope.

Make sure you are calling like below,

```
<body ng-app='PA' ng-controller="dynamicDemoController as demo">
   {{demo.A}}
   <button ng-click="demo.edit()">edit</button>
   <button ng-click="demo.printIt()">print</button>
</body>
```

It works fine here

**[DEMO](https://plnkr.co/edit/49nKhbCoosECDKuorzfh?p=preview)**

Comment: This better explain my scenario: https://plnkr.co/edit/5J4VH9WjYYH4pzgI2BmS?p=preview

Comment: That is because you refering the controlelr again, it gets re initialized. so default value is set as hello

Comment: @RoccoMusolino got it sorteD?

Comment: yes. I've choosen to use a Service to share data between controllers.